# Returning values with the sum query and the count query

Tags: sql, variables, select, stored-procedures, transactions

**Update again**

I have 2 tables `TestMain` (*Id*, *Name*) and `Ref` (*Id*, *Name*, *RefId*) with a foreign key relationship between the *TestMain's Id* and the *Ref's RefId*. These are 2 queries:

```
SELECT  T.Id, T.Name, COUNT(T.Name) AS COUNTNAME 
FROM TestMain AS T
INNER JOIN Ref AS T1
ON T.[Id] = T1.[RefId]
GROUP BY T.Name,T.Id
ORDER BY T.Id


SELECT SUM(COUNTNAME)
  FROM (
  SELECT  T.Id, COUNT(T.Name) AS COUNTNAME 
  FROM TestMain AS T
  INNER JOIN Ref AS T1
  ON T.[Id] = T1.[RefId]
  GROUP BY T.Name,T.Id
  ) AS SUMOFCOUNTNAME
```

And my stored procedure uses 2 queries on top to return values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnValues 
    @Name nvarchar(50) output,
    @Sum int output,
    @Count int output,
    @OutId int output 
AS
BEGIN
   SET XACT_ABORT ON
   BEGIN  TRAN 
    BEGIN TRY

      SELECT  @OutId = T.Id, @Name = T.Name, @Count = COUNT(T.Name) 
      FROM TestMain AS T
      INNER JOIN Ref AS T1
      ON T.[Id] = T1.[RefId]
      GROUP BY T.Name,T.Id
      ORDER BY T.Id

      SELECT @Sum = SUM(COUNTNAME)
      FROM (
        SELECT  T.Id, COUNT(T.Name) AS COUNTNAME 
        FROM TestMain AS T
        INNER JOIN Ref AS T1
        ON T.[Id] = T1.[RefId]
        GROUP BY T.Name,T.Id
        ) AS SUMOFCOUNTNAME

    COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
END
```

My problem is how to return variables: `@Name`, `@Sum`, `@Count`, `@OutId` with only one query. I don't want to use 2 queries, I seem very bad with my way.

This is TestMain's data:

```
Id  Name
1   TestName1
2   TestName2
3   TestName3
4   TestName4
5   TestName5
6   TestName6
7   TestName7
8   TestName8
9   TestName9
10  TestName10
```

This is Ref's data

```
Id  Name    RefId
1   TestRef1    1
2   TestRef2    2
3   TestRef3    2
4   TestRef4    3
5   TestRef5    3
6   TestRef6    3
7   TestRef7    4
8   TestRef8    4
9   TestRef9    4
10  TestRef10   4
11  TestRef11   5
12  TestRef12   5
13  TestRef13   5
```

I want get `@Sum` but don't use the last query.

Comment: Can You give an Output as Example.

Comment: @RJ1990 Can you tell me more about your ideas ??

Comment: If the first query returns only a single row, such that it makes *sense* to assign the results to scalar variables, I fail to see how the second query can return any result different that what `@Count` already contains.

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample. I'd still be interested if you can explain any situation where `@Sum` and `@Count` wouldn't be equal.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry, this is example with my question. You can run my sp without `@Id` and `Having T.Id = @Id`. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @lazycatit : Is T.ID column has Unique or Primary key constraint? Also are You sure that you are select `COUNT(T.Name)`, Since the same column is used in `Group by` clause.

Comment: `T.Id` is Unique. If you don't use `COUNT(T.Name)`, you can use `COUNT(T.Id)` and `SUM(COUNTID)`. I think it doesn't a difference about result.

Comment: I am not seeing any difference between `@sum` and `@count`

Comment: Please see again my comments " You can run my sp without @Id and Having T.Id = @Id"

Comment: Remove `@Id, @OutId` and `Having T.Id = @Id`, and you can see the different

Comment: Can somebody help me?